# Proving the double differential of z = -z implies z= sinx

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

In common usage, we know that $$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=-z\,$$ implies $z$ is of the form $a\sin x + b\cos x$. Is there a proof for the same. I was trying to arrive at the desired function but couldn't understand how to get these trigonometric functions in the equations by integration. Does it require the use of taylor polynomial expansion of $\sin x\, \text {or}\, \cos x$?

Comment: The fact that $z(x) = a \sin(x) + b \cos(x)$ is a solution of $\frac{d^2 z}{dx^2} = -z$ can be proven by simply filling it in in the equation. If you want to prove that is the unique solution, you will need the theorem for uniqueness and existence of solutions to second order differential equations. If neither of those things are what you're looking for, it's not really clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @Demophilus using the said form of z is like proving the theorem in reverse, but then we end up neglecting maybe some kind of function that could have been a solution. I wanted to see if this was a unique solution. that's why i am looking for a derivation of z-function but without any assumption imposed on it

Comment: @Demophilus i noticed you have mentioned a theorem for uniqueness of solution, could you elaborate on its application here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume the solution is of the form 
$$z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n+\cdots$$
then
$$
z''
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} 
=1\cdot2a_2+2\cdot3a_3x+3\cdot4a_4x^2+\cdots
$$
from $z''=-z$ then with arbitrary $a_0$ and $a_1$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
 a_2=-\frac{1}{1\times2}a_0 ~~~,~~~ 
 a_4=-\frac{1}{3\times4}a_2=\dfrac{1}{4!}a_0   ~~,~~~ 
 a_6=-\frac{1}{5\times6}a_4=-\dfrac{1}{6!}a_0  ~~,~~~ \cdots\\
&&
 a_3=-\frac{1}{2\times3}a_1 ~~~,~~~ 
 a_5=-\frac{1}{4\times5}a_3=\dfrac{1}{5!}a_1   ~~,~~~ 
 a_7=-\frac{1}{6\times7}a_5=-\dfrac{1}{7!}a_0  ~~,~~~ \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
then
$$z=a_0\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots\right) + a_1\left(x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots\right)=\color{blue}{a_0\cos x+a_1\sin x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$d^2z/dx^2=k^2z$$
$$z=A\exp(kx)+B\exp(-kx)$$
Now $k^2=-1$ so substitute $k=i$ and get your form

Comment: you mean exp(kx), right.

Comment: Yep! Edited now

Comment: by assuming z as the function you mentioned or the one in the quesiton, we can prove the same, what I wanted to know was of this can be done without assuming z to be a certain specific function of x

Comment: @SiddharthJha Some methods like **series method** don't need assuming a certain specific function.

Comment: @MyGlasses can you elaborate on the method as to how we get to the final form

Comment: @SiddharthJha Are you familiar with series method for solving ODEs?

Answer (score 0):

To show that $A\cos x +B\sin x$ are the ONLY solutions: For any $P,Q\in \Bbb R$ there exist $A, B \in \Bbb R$ such that $A\cos x +B \sin x$ is a solution to $(f''=-f\land f(0)=P\land f'(0)=Q).$

If $z(x)$ is any solution to $(z''=-z\land z(0)=P\land z'(0)=Q)$ then $y(x)=z(x)-(A\cos x+B\sin x)$ satisfies $(y''=-y\land y(0)=y'(0)=0).$

We show this implies $\forall x\; (y(x)=0)$ as follows:

Suppose by contradiction that $y(x_1)\ne 0$ for some $x_1>0$.  (The case $y(x_1)\ne 0$ for some $x_1<0$ is handled similarly.)

Then $x_0=\max \{x\geq 0: \forall x'\in [0,x]\;(y(x')=0)\}$ exists. We have $y(x_0)=0 .$ And we have $0\leq x_0<x_1.$

If $x_0=0$ then $0=y(0)=y'(x_0).$ If $x_0>0$ then $y$ is constantly $0$ on $[0,x_0]$ so $y'(x_0)=0.$ So  $y'(x_0)=0$ regardless of whether $x_0=0$ or $x_0>0.$

For any $r>0$  there exists $s_r\in (0,r)$ such that $$y(x_0+r)=y(x_0)+ry'(x_0)+r^2y''(x_0+s_r)/2=r^2y''(x_0+s_r)/2=r^2y(x_0+s_r)/2.$$ However  we  can take $r_1$ such that $0<r_1<\min (1,x_1-x_0)$ and we can take $r_2\in [0,r_1]$  such that $$|y(x_0+r_2)| =\max \{|y(x)|: x\in [x_0,x_0+r_1]\}.$$ We have $|y(x_0+r_2)|>0$ (by the def'n of $ x_0$ and because $x_0+r_1>x_0$.) So $$0<|y(x_0+r_2)|=|(r_2)^2y(x_0+s_{r_2})/2|
\leq $$ $$\leq  |(r_2)^2y(x+r_2)/2|\leq |y(x_0+r_2)|/2$$ which implies $0<|y(x_0+r_2)|\leq |y(x_0+r_2)|/2,$ which is  absurd.

Comment: Let $y^{(j)}$ denote the $j$-th derivative of $y.$  Suppose $y=\sum_{j=1}^n A_jy^{(j)} $ where $n>0$ and $A_1,..., A_n$  are constants.  By the same method as in my answer, if $y(0)=0=y^{(j)}(0)=0$  for $1\leq j\leq n-1$ then $y=0.$